# Home to skip shipping address step during checkout in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping-address

In case of virtual products, we do not need a shipping step so customer directly goes for payment step during checkout.

I have a simple product and a custom field `delivery_type` in `quote` table. `delivery_type` field's value is updated on the cart page by selecting what is the delivery type (home/store).

If the value of `delivery_type` is `store` shipping step is not required and the customer should see only payment step similar to virtual products at checkout. Can anyone guide me on how I should go about customizing it?

I tried changing the value of field `is_virtual` to 1 in `quote` and `quote_item` table manually but it does not make any difference. I have logged `window.checkoutConfig.quoteData.is_virtual` which still shows 0.

Comment: vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\js\model\quote.js have method name isVirtual: function () {  return !!Number(quoteData['is_virtual']);} need to be extend this function hopefully its will be work for you

Comment: Just to test I changed return value of `isVirtual` function to true. Is shows message _No Payment method available_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please have a look at this class

Magento\Quote\Model\Quote

in this class you have this method  **isVirtual()** [image attached]

if the return result is true, Magento will skip the Shipping Step.

You can override this method or create a "after plugin" (recommended) to change the return value as you want

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot.. for this post, it really helped me to achieve my requirement.

Comment: If a different type of product is available in the cart then add to cart is not working afterIsVirtual().

Answer (score 0):

Found generic way to skip shipping, not just for virtual products, in my case I have table driven shipping rate according to zip code (distance), and shipping screen is redundant. The idea is waiting for the shipping screen to load and then approve and continue automatically.

1. Create **requirejs-config.js** file in
   `app/code/[Vendor]/[Modulename]/view/`
   folder and add below code [see why](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/requirejs.html).

```
var config = {
   paths: {
      'Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping': '[Vendor]_[Modulename]/js/view/shipping'
   }
};
```

2. Copy **Shipping.js** from magento source folder:
   `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view` to your module in the following folder:
   `app/code/[Vendor]/[Modulename]/view/frontend/web/js/view`
3. Revising the **Shipping.js** to include the following code:

```js
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/form',
    'ko',
    'Magento_Customer/js/model/customer',
    'Magento_Customer/js/model/address-list',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/address-converter',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/create-shipping-address',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/select-shipping-address',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rates-validator',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-address/form-popup-state',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-service',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/select-shipping-method',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rate-registry',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/set-shipping-information',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/checkout-data-resolver',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/checkout-data',
    'uiRegistry',
    'mage/translate',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rate-service'
], function (
    $,
    _,
    Component,
    ko,
    customer,
    addressList,
    addressConverter,
    quote,
    createShippingAddress,
    selectShippingAddress,
    shippingRatesValidator,
    formPopUpState,
    shippingService,
    selectShippingMethodAction,
    rateRegistry,
    setShippingInformationAction,
    stepNavigator,
    modal,
    checkoutDataResolver,
    checkoutData,
    registry,
    $t
) {
    'use strict';

    var popUp = null;

    // ### 1st revision start
    var timer = setInterval(function() {
        // Wait until all page was loaded, using Next button div id
        var nextVar = $( "#shipping-method-buttons-container");
        if (nextVar.length > 0) {
            clearInterval(timer);
            // Make sure 'Next' button is visible
            var nextBtn = $("button", nextVar);
            if (nextBtn.is(":visible")) {
                __self.setShippingInformation();
            }

        }
    }, 100);

    // ### 1st revision end

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Magento_Checkout/shipping',
            shippingFormTemplate: 'Magento_Checkout/shipping-address/form',
            shippingMethodListTemplate: 'Magento_Checkout/shipping-address/shipping-method-list',
            shippingMethodItemTemplate: 'Magento_Checkout/shipping-address/shipping-method-item'
        },
        visible: ko.observable(!quote.isVirtual()),
        errorValidationMessage: ko.observable(false),
        isCustomerLoggedIn: customer.isLoggedIn,
        isFormPopUpVisible: formPopUpState.isVisible,
        isFormInline: addressList().length === 0,
        isNewAddressAdded: ko.observable(false),
        saveInAddressBook: 1,
        quoteIsVirtual: quote.isVirtual(),

        /**
         * @return {exports}
         */
        initialize: function () {
            var self = this,
                hasNewAddress,
                fieldsetName = 'checkout.steps.shipping-step.shippingAddress.shipping-address-fieldset';

            // ### last revision start
            __self = self;
            // ### last revision end

            this._super();
            ...
```

Using `setInterval` is not best practice, but couldn't find a way to trigger `setShippingInformation()` after the shipping screen fully loaded. Tried `$(document).ready` as well as `$(window).on("load", function)` but the document wasn't fully loaded even then, making the call to `setShippingInformation()` to be ignored.

Hope this helps anyone.

Comment: what are you doing with this code? how can you skip as like this?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: __self is not defined

Comment: I'm calling the function as if you pressed the Next button, I think you missed the 2nd revision in the code:
__self = self;